# In Firefox why does HTML button size decrease when javascript changes the background color?

Tags: javascript, html

In Firefox, and maybe other browsers, why does HTML button size decrease when JavaScript changes the background color?

How do I stop it from happening?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script>
      function fnHello()
      {
        document.getElementById("idHello").style.background = '#ff0000';
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="idHello" type="button" value="Hello" onclick="fnHello();" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not actually the button size shrinking, but the outline and the border properties are affecting its size, which is default behaviuor for different browsers. Look at the following snippet.

Disabling border and outline, it is not happening anymore.

```css
input[type=button] {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

input[type=button]:focus {
  border: none;
  outline: none
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <script>
    function fnHello() {
      document.getElementById("idHello").style.background = '#ff0000';
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="idHello" type="button" value="Hello" onclick="fnHello();" />
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting this CSS:

```
    border: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    margin-top:-2px; 
    margin-bottom: -2px;
```

Reference: https://davidwalsh.name/firefox-buttons

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your style ,

```
 input{
  border : 0px
 }
```

I checked in the firefox Inspector and found that the default firefox button has a border of 3 (horizontally) and 0 vertically and when you change the background the border becomes 2 horizontally. If you set the border to 0 explicitly , the size will not decrease.